# Data Not Showing in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I'm attempting to combine a couple of different chart demos from Highcharts.

My examples are: [Data classes and popup](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/data-class-two-ranges/) and [Small US with data labels](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/us-data-labels/)

I want the map from the first with the popup feature of the second. I need to connect the map to my own google spreadsheet but for now I'm just trying to get the data from the first example to work.

This is what I have so far but can't seem to get any data in the map. I thought I had a `joinBy` problem, and I may still, but when I set `joinBy` to null I thought "the map items are joined by their position in the array", yet nothing happened.

https://jsfiddle.net/9eq6mydv/

```
$(function () {
// Load the data from a Google Spreadsheet
// https://docs.google.com/a/highsoft.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_GB&hl=en_GB&key=0AoIaUO7wH1HwdFJHaFI4eUJDYlVna3k5TlpuXzZubHc&output=html
Highcharts.data({

    googleSpreadsheetKey: '0AoIaUO7wH1HwdDFXSlpjN2J4aGg5MkVHWVhsYmtyVWc',
    googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 1,

    // custom handler for columns
    parsed: function (columns) {

        // Make the columns easier to read
        var keys = columns[0],
            names = columns[1],
            percent = columns[10],
        // Initiate the chart
        options = {
            chart : {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'map',
                borderWidth : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'US presidential election 2008 result'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,' +
                    '_2008#Election_results">Wikipedia</a>'
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                enableButtons: false
            },

            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                valueDecimals: 0,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)'
            },

            colorAxis: {
                dataClasses: [{
                    from: -100,
                    to: 0,
                    color: '#C40401',
                    name: 'McCain'
                }, {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 100,
                    color: '#0200D0',
                    name: 'Obama'
                }]
            },

            series : [{
                data : data,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    format: '{point.code}',
                    style: {
                        textTransform: 'uppercase'
                    }
                },
                mapData: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/custom/us-small']),
                joinBy: keys,
                name: 'Democrats margin',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: pointClick
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    ySuffix: ' %'
                },
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }, {
                type: 'mapline',
                data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/custom/us-small'], 'mapline'),
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        };

        /**
         * Event handler for clicking points. Use jQuery UI to pop up
         * a pie chart showing the details for each state.
         */
        function pointClick() {
            var row = this.options.row,
                $div = $('<div></div>')
                    .dialog({
                        title: this.name,
                        width: 400,
                        height: 300
                    });

            window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: $div[0],
                    type: 'pie',
                    width: 370,
                    height: 240
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Votes',
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Obama',
                        color: '#0200D0',
                        y: parseInt(columns[3][row], 10)
                    }, {
                        name: 'McCain',
                        color: '#C40401',
                        y: parseInt(columns[4][row], 10)
                    }],
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> {point.percentage:.1f}%'
                    }
                }]
            });
        }

        // Read the columns into the data array
        var data = [];
        $.each(keys, function (i, key) {
            data.push({
                key: key,//.toUpperCase(),
                value: parseFloat(percent[i]),
                name: names,
                row: i
            });
        });

        // Initiate the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.Map(options);
    },

    error: function () {
        $('#container').html('<div class="loading">' +
            '<i class="icon-frown icon-large"></i> ' +
            'Error loading data from Google Spreadsheets' +
            '</div>');
    }
});
});
```

UPDATE:

I wanted to share with everyone my final solution. Although Ondkloss did a magnificent job answering my question the popup feature still didn't work and this is because I forgot to include the jQuery for the `.dialog` call. Once I included that I had an empty popup with a [highchart error 17](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17), this is because the highmaps.js code doesn't include the pie chart class. So I had to add the `highcharts.js` code and include `map.js` module afterward. You can see my [final jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rj22puco/).

Thanks again to Ondkloss for the excellent answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here mostly comes down to the use of `joinBy`. Also to correct it there are some required changes to your `data` and `mapData`.

Currently your `joinBy` is an array of strings, like `["al", "ak", ...]`. This is quite simply not an accepted format of the `joinBy` option. You can read up on the details in [the API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#series%3Cmap%3E.joinBy), but the simplest approach is to have a attribute in common in `data` and `mapData` and then supply a string in `joinBy` which then joins those two arrays by that attribute. For example:

```
series : [{
    data : data,
    mapData: mapData,
    joinBy: "hc-key",
]
```

Here the `"hc-key"` attribute must exist in both `data` and `mapData`.

Here's how I'd create the `data` variable in your code:

```
var data = [];
$.each(keys, function (i, key) {
    if(i != 0)
        data.push({
            "hc-key": "us-"+key,
            code: key.toUpperCase(),
            value: parseFloat(percent[i]),
            name: names[i],
            row: i
        });
});
```

This skips the first key, which is just `"Key"` (the title of the column). Here we make the `"hc-key"` fit the format of the `"hc-key"` in our map data. An example would be `"us-al"`. The rest is just metadata that will be joined in. Note that you were referencing your data in the options prior to filling it with data, so this has to be moved prior to this.

This is how I'd create the `mapData` variable in your code:

```
var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/custom/us-small']);

// Process mapdata
$.each(mapData, function () {
    var path = this.path,
        copy = { path: path };

    // This point has a square legend to the right
    if (path[1] === 9727) {

        // Identify the box
        Highcharts.seriesTypes.map.prototype.getBox.call(0, [copy]);

        // Place the center of the data label in the center of the point legend box
        this.middleX = ((path[1] + path[4]) / 2 - copy._minX) / (copy._maxX - copy._minX);
        this.middleY = ((path[2] + path[7]) / 2 - copy._minY) / (copy._maxY - copy._minY);

    }
    // Tag it for joining
    this.ucName = this.name.toUpperCase();
});
```

The first part is your "standard map data". The rest is to correctly center the labels for the popout states, and gotten directly from the example.

And voila, see [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/9eq6mydv/1/) to witness your map in action.

I suggest doing some `console.log`-ing to see how `data` and `mapData` have the `hc-key` in common and that leads to the joining of the data in the series.

Comment: WOW! This is a wonderfully thoughtful answer. Thanks for you help. I don't just have a solution I have an understanding of what I am doing.